# "Double Clicking" to mean, going in depth

Tags: expressions, word-usage, phrase-usage

I have been recently hearing the expression "double clicking" to mean 'going in depth'.
For example:

> We will **double click** on this topic later on when required.

I have never heard of such a usage before. So, I just want to know if it's a common phrase? Any other details regarding its origins, usage etc. will also be helpful.

Comment: Aren't the origins fairly easy to guess? Double click on a piece of some webpage, and it opens up and shows you that aspect in more depth.

Comment: As Peter says, the "origin" is trivial. Any any opinions regarding "prevalence" will simply be opinions - OP has obviously encountered the usage before, but I haven't. I don't plan on using it in future either - it sounds seriously geeky to me.

Comment: @FumbleFingers "Geek" is in now though, Isn't it? To me it actually sounds not so much geeky (which I personally would like) and more the sort of awful managerial jargon of the sort "I enhance core competencies by leveraging platforms." (see http://dilbert.com/search_results?page=7&terms=buying+friends where I stole it from).

Comment: @PeterShor Websites more often will use single clicks to navigate. Double clicking in websites is not so common. Double clicking comes from desktop computing such as opening folders or applications in MS Windows. For the OP, I do not think it is a common phrase and would recommend using alternatives such *drill down* or *explore*

Comment: Never heard it before.  I'm guessing you're hearing it a lot because some highly-placed guy in your company picked it up and is using it, and everyone else is copying him.  (I agree with DRF that is sounds like another piece of terrible managerspeak.)

Comment: I'm surprised it has taken this long to rear its ugly head to be honest- It makes perfect sense in a modern corporate environment, if you are into that kind of thing :) Having now heard it, and despite my best efforts, I may be unable to prevent it from slipping out in some meeting...

Comment: @PeterShor, I know the origin looks straight forward, but i just wanted to know if there are any alternate views on that. Because a lot of times, the origin of something is not the most obvious answer. But, i see your point.

Comment: @MarvMills, I know, right? Even though its a new usage for me, this expression just creeps into my regular language quite often.

Comment: I suspect not merely corporate manager speak at work here, but corporate sales rep manager speak. It may be just a coincidence, but DoubleClick (now owned by Google) is a major force among companies that serve directed online advertisements to innocent Internet users. In my mind the very verb _double-click_ is tainted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a lifelong US person (who does interact with worldwide English through forums such as this one on occasion), I've never heard that usage. I'm also a professional Software Engineer, so you'd think if such a computer-usage metaphor was A Thing, I at least would not be the last to hear it.

I would assume its a metaphor for the action required to open files and programs in a typical [WIMP interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WIMP_(computing)).

That doesn't mean its not out there in pockets somewhere. Clearly it is for someone. But I wouldn't throw it at a wider audience just yet.

Comment: I am a Software Engineer myself, so i guess that sort of comes by the trade. In fact, the person i have heard it from has been in the industry for 20 or more years.